# Inserting Table of Figures in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I am using a template file for my document in MS Word Mac 2011. I have five chapters. The figures of the first three chapters automatically come when I update the Table of Figures, but the fourth and fifth chapter figures have a problem as seen in the figure below. No reference is found by the Table of Figures for almost any picture in the fourth and fifth chapters, giving an error.

[image].

Comment: Assuming you already updated all the fields in your document, if change tracking is switched on, I suggest you make a copy of your document, accept all changes, update all the fields in the document twice (cmd-A, F9 or fn-F9) again (probably a couple of times as the ToCs will probably be updated before the other fields. As always, make sure Word is up to date (currently 14.4.1 I think).